# Несколько вопросов о запуске сервера Mule ESB

Tags: java, java-ee, веб-сервер

Почему при запуске из командной строки выдавало сообщение The Mule service was launched, but failed to start. А в логах было видно что он не может найти некий DLL:

```
Error in WrapperListener.start callback.  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 

Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path, C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-32.dll (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path, C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-32.dll (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)]
```

По такому пути последней папки Temp вообще не было.
Я нашел такой же файл, только в пользовательской папке Temp. Скопировал. Заработало. Но я не думаю что это правильно - просто скопировать, возможно у меня что то не так установилось и я не могу понять что именно. Может кто-нибудь знает в чем причина такой ошибки?

И еще вопрос, Mule может запускать только администратор компьютера? Пробую запускать с учетки которой права админа присвоены но выскакивает следующее при запуске:

```
    OpenSCManager failed - ╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях. (0x5)
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: Насчёт dll-ки: почему бы и нет? Не там искал файл. Вы ему дали его и всё заработало. Это ведь не другой dll с тем же именем :)
Насчёт прав - вполне возможно, что учётке не хватает определённых прав. Сервер поднимает сервис, слушает порт, пишет логи и т.д. и т.п. Возможно, у вашей учётки не хватает каких-то прав.

Comment: Ну в принципе думаю да, для дальнейшей работы моего решения с подстановкой может и достаточно. Приложения разворачиваются, в логах все в порядке. Просто интересно что я мог не учесть при установке и может ли это потом как то отразится на работе.

Comment: Подсуньте другой dll с тем же именем. Если заработает, то нужно искать проблему, если нет, то скорее всего всё в порядке )